# Headless browser on android supporting websockets?

Tags: java, android, headless-browser

Well I'm working on a project which requires me to do a couple of automated things on a website. Its all working good. I've setup WebView and binded JS interface with Java on android to communicate with it.

It works great. But it is really ugly and painful. Also, I'm making WebView full screen and invisible in a service (I need to do that in background). The reason is that the project I'm doing uses `websocket` to make a request. So I cannot simply GET/POST with Java.

Moreover, the javascript used by the website is too complicated to deobfuscate and scractch out the API used by websocket to communicate (it just shows `Binary OPCode 2` in Frames tab in chrome debugger)

So what I'm getting to is, is there any easy way to go headless on android which supports websockets?

Comment: did you ever find a solution (or a workaround) for your problem?

Comment: @soey I deobfuscated the js and created a minimal webview with websocket in service which I did not add to window screen and it worked fine.

Comment: did you find any way to solve this problem ? I have the same problems , but i have no new ideals ? Can we build a headless browser use NDK ??